# Which Nikon-mount lens is better for shooting birds and wildlife, Nikon 200-500mm or Sigma 150-600mm?

Tags: lens, nikon, autofocus, sigma, image-stabilization

I am finding it difficult to decide between the Nikon 200-500mm and the Sigma 150-600mm lenses for wildlife photography (especially birds). I have read lots of review for both the lenses, but I still have not reached a conclusion. Points to consider:

1. I need fast and excellent auto focus.
2. Bokeh
3. Great image stabilization. I have noticed with Sigma, corners are very sharp in some some images, whereas with Nikon corners are quite bitter. (I also understand image stabilization depends upon subject and my hand.)
4. Last but not least, price.

Comment: What is your question? What confuses you about these two lenses?

Comment: Which one is best for wildlife photography.

Comment: Comparison:
https://photographylife.com/nikon-200-500mm-vs-tamron-150-600mm-vs-sigma-150-600mm-c/6

Answer (score 2):

I did a detailed analysis of the Sigma 150-600 Contemporary version, but haven't tried the Nikkor 200-500.  Sample pictures give you an idea of the bokeh and sharpness.  Here's my link:

https://www.photoartfromscience.com/single-post/2015/9/3/Sigma-150600-f563-DG-OS-HSM-C-Review

Get the Sigma USB dock and take the time to calibrate it, or else don't bother to buy the lens.  Focus calibration is that important.